# How to give border-color to ionic slider bullets

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I have ionic slide box, I want to give border color white for active bullet.
[here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB) is live example to edit [demo](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB) if you see active bullet has black color, and rest inactive have gray, I want border for active bullet that should look like as below img.

Here is what I tried so far,
I tried with stroke

```
.slider-pager .slider-pager-page.active {
    color: #000;
    fill: #000;
    stroke: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* height: 17px; */
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

then I tried with

```
.slider-pager .slider-pager-page.active {
  border:1px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

[image]

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB
```

Comment: can you please show what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: @dubes please check my updated answer

Comment: @dubes any suggestions????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the native styling of ionic slider bullets with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements

```
i.icon.ion-record {
  position:relative;
}

.slider-pager span.slider-pager-page {
  opacity:1;
}

.slider-pager span.slider-pager-page.active i.icon.ion-record:after {
  border-color:black;
}
i.icon.ion-record:after {
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:2px;
  margin:auto;
  content:"";
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border:4px solid white;
  border-radius:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

i.icon.ion-record:before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  content:"";
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border:6px solid red;
  border-radius:100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

here is an example of a possible modification: 
http://codepen.io/dimshik/pen/yaBOqY